# Count days in date range?

Tags: sql, mysql, date-range

I have a query like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS amount
FROM daily_individual_tracking
WHERE sales = 'YES'
AND daily_individual_tracking_date BETWEEN '2010-01-01' AND '2010-03-31'
```

I am selected from a date range. Is there a way to also get the total days in the date range?

Comment: Are you sure you have data for each day in the range?

Comment: Could you give an example of what the query should output? And maybe even some example data?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Not really clear if you are looking for

```
DATEDIFF('2010-03-31', '2010-01-01')
```

or

```
COUNT(DISTINCT daily_individual_racking_date)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the MySQL `datediff` function:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF('2010-01-01','2010-01-31') AS DiffDays
```

It should return a floating point, where `1.0` represents a single day.

And for MS SQL use ,

```
SELECT DATEDIFF( day ,'2010-01-01','2010-01-31') AS DiffDays
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to count? The total number of distinct values of daily_individual_tracking_date? Do you need it in the same query as the count(*) query?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what SQL server you're using.

If you're using MS-SQL Server, you can use the function [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which SQL you are using. TSQL has a DATEDIFF that will count the number of days between two dates. See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx)